# calling multiple https request inside express route in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, rest

1

I have route like this:

router.get('/test', async(req, res)=>{
});

i used to use request module to perform the http calls.

But now, I want to call multiple http calls and combine the responses into single JSON object

How to do it?

Comment: It's irrelevant what lib you use to make HTTP requests: all of them are async one or other way and you always can make requests in parallel using `Promise.all`. Or you can simply makes requests one after another if their results depend on each other.

Answer (score 1):

With a method marked as `async` you can use the `await` keyword to make the http calls synchronous, ie wait for the resonse.

```
router.get('/test', async(req, res)=>{ 

    // first call    
    var result1 = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    var resultJson1 = await result1.json();
    var resultObject1 = JSON.parse(resultJson1);

    // second call    
    var result2 = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    var resultJson1 = await result1.json();
    var resultObject2 = JSON.parse(resultJson2);

    var combinedResult = resultObject1.fieldName + resultObject2.anotherFieldName


 res.send(JSON.stringify(combinedResult));

});
```